# Unique filename of uploaded file using the django FORM

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to generate a unique filename for the uploaded file using the Django forms. I've tried **uuid_upload_path** app but that app doesn't work with the form. Below is my code

**Forms.py**

```
class HelpGuideForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    image = forms.ImageField(required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = Helpguide
        fields = ['title', 'image']
```

**Models.py**

```
from uuid_upload_path import upload_to

class HelpguideImage(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want a unique name for all uploaded files. something like sd564sadasd61.jpg. I'm using Django 2.2

Answer (score 2):

In your Model you can set the upload_to of the imagefield to a function and then generate the uuid.

A very simple (untested) example:

```
import uuid

Class MyModel(models.Model):
    def get_path(instance, filename):
        extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
        uuid = uuid.uuid1().hex
        return f'path/to/file/{uuid}.{extension}'

    image = ImageField(upload_to=get_path)
```

Comment: I'm using a similar setup in one of my own applications (though not with a form, but I'm sure how that should have any impact in this case). What is not working?

Comment: I've updated my code and you can see my models file. I've used the above app and when I upload a file from the Django admin it's working. But when I try to do the same using the form on the frontend, the original filename keeps saving. No unique name is generated.

Comment: I have honestly no idea why it wouldn't work with a modelform. I don't have a lot of experience with uploading files through (model)forms. Did you try both that package and my 'manual' method?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand of your problem, you can set `initial` for FORM class when initialising it. like:

```
help_guide_form = HelpGuideForm(initial={'headline': uuid.uuid4().hex}, instance= Helpguide)
```

from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values). Also see the [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/) reference.